# scripts wont delete separately

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got both scripts to work independently when button is pressed. However when I try to press one of the delete buttons it gets rid of both of them. Ive separated the codes to classes soo it should only delete the corresponding section inside the function.. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.ddd').on('click', myFunction1);
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $('#demo1').empty();
});


$('.eee').on('click', myFunction2);
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $('#demo2').empty();
});

function myFunction1() {
  var demo1 = $('#demo1');

  if (!demo1.html().length) {
    demo1.html('<div id="formwrap2" class="ddd" name="ddd"><div id="ddd"><div id="driverinfo">Home Info<button type="button" name="remove"  id="test2" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">Remove Home</span></button></div>test1</div>');
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var demo2 = $('#demo2');

  if (!demo2.html().length) {
    demo2.html('<div id="formwrap2" class="eee" name="test"><div id="eee"><div id="driverinfo">Renters Info<button type="button" name="remove"  id="test2" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">Remove Renters</span></button></div>test2</div>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" name="ddd" id="test1" class="ddd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add Home</span></button>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<hr>

<button type="button" name="eee" id="test2" class="eee"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add RENTERS</span></button>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: `$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {` is repeated twice, once per demo.

Comment: Inside the delete function, try accessing the parent and just bind it once. `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your code does:

```js
$('.ddd').on('click', myFunction1);
/* 1. When `.ddd` is clicked, execute myFunction1() */

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $('#demo1').empty();
});
/* 2. Any click inside `<body>` done on 
 * an element with class="remove", should empty `#demo1` 
 */

$('.eee').on('click', myFunction2);
/* 3.  When `.eee` is clicked, execute myFunction2() */

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $('#demo2').empty();
});
/* 4. Any click inside `<body>` done on 
 * an element with class="remove", should empty `#demo2` 
 */
```

If you take into consideration comments 2 and 4, you'll notice that any click on `<body>`, if on an element with `class="remove"` will empty both `#demo1` and `#demo2` elements.

Let's replace 2 and 4 with one single function which empties closest `<p>` element. If that doesn't make sense in your actual app, use a custom class for this purpose (i.e.: `.to-be-emptied` - and add that class to the `<button>` parent you want emptied on click).

```js
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('p').empty();
});
```

See it working:

```js
$('.ddd').on('click', myFunction1);
$('.eee').on('click', myFunction2);

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).closest('p').empty();
});

function myFunction1() {
  var demo1 = $('#demo1');

  if (!demo1.html().length) {
    demo1.html('<div id="formwrap2" class="ddd" name="ddd"><div id="ddd"><div id="driverinfo">Home Info<button type="button" name="remove"  id="test2" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">Remove Home</span></button></div>test1</div>');
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var demo2 = $('#demo2');

  if (!demo2.html().length) {
    demo2.html('<div id="formwrap2" class="eee" name="test"><div id="eee"><div id="driverinfo">Renters Info<button type="button" name="remove"  id="test2" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">Remove Renters</span></button></div>test2</div>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" name="ddd" id="test1" class="ddd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add Home</span></button>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<hr>

<button type="button" name="eee" id="test2" class="eee"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Add RENTERS</span></button>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Another issue with your current code is it allows duplicated ids in the page (`formwrap2`, `driverinfo`, ...)
I cannot emphasize enough how detrimental that can be to your health. In severe cases, it leads to self-inflicted hair loss.

Comment: This worked and thank you for explaining it. and not just providing a solution